# How to Store String[] in android studio app?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I was just trying out this code
but it subsequently turned my phone into a black screen and **after some time of black screen it was able to load data**.

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(my_Arraylist<String>_here);
    editor.putString("task list", json);
    editor.apply();
```

**Can anyone please tell me the way to Escape from that black screen?**

Comment: Better do it in the background thread. The Dataset that you are saving in SharedPreference will be huge and running it in the main thread is blocking your UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(my_Arraylist < String > _here);
                editor.putString("task list", json);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Answer (score 1):

You can as well execute the code in the runUiThread method...

```
//This method will run your code in the background and update the UI when it is don
runUiThread(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
     //Your code here
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = gson.toJson(my_Arraylist<String>_here);
     editor.putString("task list", json);
     editor.apply();
   }
});
```